# layout difference between IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a site ([www.jamesalder.co.uk](http://www.jamesalder.co.uk)) which is not rendering properly in IE8 and below.

Here it is in IE8:
[image: in IE8]

And in IE9 and everything else:
[image: in IE9]

As you can see, the search box has moved from top right to the wrong place.
The html for the search box is:

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="/media/header_images/ts-hutton_2.jpg" title="Victorian Paintings at James Alder Fine Art" alt="Victorian Paintings at James Alder Fine Art" "="">
    <form id="search-form" action="/search">
             <label id="search-label">Search the Site</label>
             <input type="image" src="/static/images/sign-up.gif" value="search" id="search-button">
             <input type="text" name="q" id="search-input">
    </form>

</div>
```

It seems as though it is totally missing out the following CSS, in that if I disable this CSS, it has the same effect:

```
#search-form {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Does IE9 have some kind of problem with CSS on forms? Should I put it in a div?

As for the images below that which have decided not to float any more, I have no idea.

Are there any best practices or good resources about getting sites to behave across older versions of IE, or should I just use conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was actually caused by malformed html. I had tags which looked like this:

```
<img src="/media/homepage_images/all-paintings-sale.jpg" 
     alt="All Victorian Paintings for Sale" 
     title="All Victorian Paintings for Sale" ">
```

Notice the " at the end, which was causing everything following it to be treated as text.
Bizarrely, IE9 and everything else fixed the error automatically but IE8 and below didn't.

Comment: It’s not particularly bizarre. Browsers have historically dealt with HTML errors in different ways, because error handling wasn’t standardised in HTML until recently.

Answer (score -1):

It may cause by `<form>`.

Put your `<form id="search-form" action="/search">` element in a div.

```
<div id="header">
    <img src="..."/>
    <div id="search-form">
        <form action="/search"></form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this please.